# Blazor WASM Can't get image from database to view

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm Learning Blazor + WEB API. In the client project, I get all the data from the server into the view, except for the image.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

It's my file upload service:

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile(Stream msFile, string pictureName)
    {
        var path = $"{_env.WebRootPath}\\images\\{pictureName}";

        var buffer = new byte[4 * 1096];

        int bytesRead;

        double totalRead = 0;

        using FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        while ((bytesRead = await msFile.ReadAsync(buffer)) != 0)
        {
            totalRead += bytesRead;
            await fs.WriteAsync(buffer);
        }

        var url = $"{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value}/";
        
        var fullPath = $"{url}images/{pictureName}";

        return fullPath;
    }
```

My razor component

```
@foreach (var prod in item.Products)
{
    <img class="d-block w-100" style="border-radius:20px;"
         src="@prod.Image">
}
```

GitHub https://github.com/ValencyJacob/PharmacyStore

Comment: Is `fullPath` supposed to be $`"{url}/images/{pictureName}"` instead of `$"{url}images/{pictureName}"`?

Comment: Nothing changes if add /

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image value you set below is just the name, but I find your stored static file and client are located in different project:

```
var pictureName = $"{pictureId}{ext}";

await _fileUpload.UploadFile(msFile, pictureName);

Model.Image = pictureName;
```

You need set the value **with the full path**(**e.g:** The `Image` value should be setted like : `https://localhost:44375/images/04c91d389a8946d7b741b5a11eb73cfc.jpg`):

```
var pictureName = $"{pictureId}{ext}";

var fullpath = await _fileUpload.UploadFile(msFile, pictureName);

Model.Image = fullpath;
```

Then you could display the images(store in `PharmacyStore.UI`) in another project(`Client.WASM`).

### Note:

The port number(`44375`) should belong to the project which store the static file(`PharmacyStore.UI`).

Comment: Thx a lot Rena!